# How to correctly type a chained functions generator function in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, types, functional-programming

In Swift in particular (but honestly I would like a good solution in any typed language) I would like to correctly type a *function combinator function*.

I do have a fair bit of experience with typed languages and generics in general but am very new to Swift. Since I have been stumbeling across this problem in Swift, that is atm. my main focus but I think I'm not sure how to do this in any types function without simply declaring everything as `Any`.

The (textbook) problem is this:

1. Write a function that takes an array of functions with a certain signature and combines them so that the output of one function is the input to the next.
2. Have the resulting function be of type `(I) -> O` where `I` is the input type of the first function in the array and `O` is the output type of the last.
3. Have each function in between (somehow) be of the type `(PreviousOut) -> MyOut` where (of course) `PreviousOut` is the output type of the function that came before.

This is what I got so far:

```swift
func combine<I, O>(_ first: (I) -> Any, _ rest: ((Any) -> Any)...) -> (I) -> O {
  return { input in 
    let firstResult = first(input)
    return rest.reduce(firstResult) {$1($0)} as! O
  }
}
```

...which works for the `I` type, but of course *"Generic parameter `O` cannot be infered"* and even if, we still do not have any kind of type savety between the combined function calls.

--Update--
Here is a fixed example with exactly 3 processor functions that does actually work. While this is obviously not what I am trying to achieve, it maybe illustrates better what is needed:

```swift
func combine<I, O, A, B>(
    _ first:@escaping (I) -> A,
    _ second:@escaping (A) -> B,
    _ third:@escaping (B) -> O
) -> (I) -> O {
  return {input in third(second(first(input)))}
}
```

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're a bit out of luck, even considering the newly introduced type parameter packs.

ATM, the only solution is to write overloaded versions of the `combine` function, and this requires setting an upper limit on how many functions you want to support.

```swift
// zero functions
func combine() {
}

// one function
func combine<I, O>(_ f: @escaping (I) -> O) -> (I) -> O {
    f
}

// two functions
func combine<I, O, T>(
    _ f1: @escaping (I) -> T,
    _ f2: @escaping (T) -> O
) -> (I) -> O {
    { f2(f1($0)) }
}

// three functions
func combine<I, O, T1, T2>(
    _ f1: @escaping (I) -> T1,
    _ f2: @escaping (T1) -> T2,
    _ f3: @escaping (T2) -> O
) -> (I) -> O {
    { f3(f2(f1($0))) }
}

// four functions
func combine<I, O, T1, T2, T3>(
    _ f1: @escaping (I) -> T1,
    _ f2: @escaping (T1) -> T2,
    _ f3: @escaping (T2) -> T3,
    _ f4: @escaping (T3) -> O
) -> (I) -> O {
    { f4(f3(f2(f1($0)))) }
}

// and so on...
```

Basically, you'll have to hand-write as many overloads as you need in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As Cristik said, it is not possible to write such a `combine` function right now. That said, if you just want to compose functions in a succinct way (without anything verbose like `compose(compose(f, g), h)`), you can just do that with your own binary operator that composes functions.

```
precedencegroup FunctionComposition {
    associativity: left
}

infix operator ~: FunctionComposition

func ~<T, U, V>(f: @escaping (T) -> U, g: @escaping (U) -> V) -> (T) -> V {
    { g(f($0)) }
}
```

Then you can write `f ~ g ~ h` and so on, for any number of functions you like.

You can additionally write a `combine`, implemented as an identity function - `combine(f ~ g ~ h)` might be more readable.

If you want to force people to use `combine`, `~` can temporarily wrap the function into a struct, then `combine` can unwrap it:

```
struct Function<T, U> {
    // fileprivate so callers cannot access this directly and must use "combine"
    fileprivate let apply: (T) -> U
}

func ~<T, U, V>(f: @escaping (T) -> U, g: @escaping (U) -> V) -> Function<T, V> {
    Function { g(f($0)) }
}

func ~<T, U, V>(f: Function<T, U>, g: @escaping (U) -> V) -> Function<T, V> {
    Function { g(f.apply($0)) }
}

func combine<T, U>(_ f: Function<T, U>) -> (T) -> U { f.apply }
```

But personally I think this is a bit overkill.

Comment: Wow ok, That's a bit of a hardcore Deep-dive into Swift.  So now I need to go and learn about binary operators and `infix`... 

Do you think something like the new macros might also be a possible solution? 

Comment: @J0sh macros can’t help here because all the arguments for a macro must be type checked first, before they are passed to your macro implementation, but type checking this is exactly what swift cannot do.